# How to remove the � UFT8 character from a char* string?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, utf-8

On the question [How to replace/ignore invalid Unicode/UTF8 characters � from C stdio.h getline()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604724/how-to-replace-ignore-invalid-unicode-utf8-characters-from-c-stdio-h-getline) I present a possible solution to the problem on the question, but I did not manage to get it working correctly.

This is the full example:

```cpp
FILE* cfilestream = fopen( "/filepath.txt", "r" );
int linebuffersize = 131072;
char* readline = (char*) malloc( linebuffersize );
char* fixedreadline = (char*) malloc( linebuffersize );

int index;
int charsread;
int invalidcharsoffset;

while( true )
{
    if( ( charsread = getline( &readline, &linebuffersize, cfilestream ) ) != -1 )
    {
        invalidcharsoffset = 0;
        for( index = 0; index < charsread; ++index )
        {
            if( readline[index] != '�' ) {
                fixedreadline[index-invalidcharsoffset] = readline[index];
            } 
            else {
                ++invalidcharsoffset;
            }
        }
        std::cerr << "fixedreadline=" << fixedreadline << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I got the following warning:

```cpp
  $ x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O0 -Wall -ggdb -std=c++11 
  source/fastfile.cpp:512:44: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
                       if( readline[index] != '�' ) {
                                              ^~~~~
```

And when running the program, it does not remove the � character from the input string `Føö�Bår`.

Comment: Do you know what character it is that you're trying to remove? That is, its byte value?

Comment: I did not understand the question. The character I would like to remove is `�`. If this is not a character, I would like to remove whatever is causing this `�` character to show up in my `char*` string.

Comment: Question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604724/how-to-replace-ignore-invalid-unicode-utf8-characters-from-c-stdio-h-getline, where it was originally asked.